# Eclipse : Creating Web Service via Apache Axis2 & Tomcat server 7

Tags: android, eclipse, tomcat, apache-axis

I'm trying to create a web service using eclipse. for that i have install tomcat server 7.and also i have set the "windows--->preference--->server(run time environment) & web service(Axis2 preference )" correctly.

when I try to create a dynamic web project it gives errors as follows.

```
     Failed while installing Axis2 web services Core 1.1.
  Reason:
     Failed while installing Axis2 web services Core 1.1.
```

I can't manage this problem please help.

Comment: What version of Eclipse?

Answer (score 2):

Lahiru,

When installing Apache Tomcat there are a few recommendations. First you want a fresh install with the latest download from http://tomcat.apache.org/download-70.cgi. I suggest Tomcat 7 as is latest version is backwards compatible.

From there you'll be able to use the .zip file after right-clicking on your Project and "Adding" it to you 'Java Build Path'. From there you will want to access your Server tab go to New->Server then select to 'Download additional adapter Servers' (or something close to that) and install a server adapter for Apache Tomcat.  I use Geronimo which works pretty well along with their core version too.

If you're still having problems after reinstalling with a fresh copy try Stopping the Server and "re-publishing" or just "publishing" your instance of Tomcat.  Sometimes that does the trick.

Hope this helps.